# Let $t\in\Bbb N,t\ge 1,(G,+,0)$ abelian group $|G|=n$ and $\gcd(t,n)=1$ Prove $f(x)=tx$ is an automorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Let $t\in\mathbb{N}, t\geq 1,\, (G,+,0)$ abelian group $|G|=n$ and $\gcd(t,n)=1$

Let $f(x)=tx=\underbrace{x+\cdots+x}_{t\text{ summands}}.$

Prove $f\in \text{Aut}(G)$

---

I proved $f$ is an homomorphism  now I want to prove $f$ is an isomorphism

- $f$ is injective because if $f(x)=f(y)$
  $$tx=ty \Longleftrightarrow tx-ty=0 \Longleftrightarrow t(x-y)=0 \Longleftrightarrow x-y=0 \Longleftrightarrow x=y $$
- $f$ is surjective?

I think it is because if $y\in f(G)$ then $y=tx$ for $x\in G$ then
$$f(x)=tx=y$$

Is this correct? I never used $\gcd(n,t)=1$ so why is that important?

Comment: What is $d$? Is it supposed to be $t$?

Comment: $d$ is never even defined?

Comment: Remember that for any endomorphism of a finite group injectivity is equivalent to surjectivity, so you just need to prove one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $\gcd(n,t)=1$, by Bézout's Theorem, there exist $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ such that

$$xt+yn=1.$$

Consider

$$\begin{align}
g:G&\to G,\\
a&\mapsto xa.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it

Comment: You're welcome, @JhonKnows.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of injectivity is incorrect. Think about what injectivity means: it means that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two elements of $G$, and $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then $x_1 = x_2$.

Your proof of surjectivity is also incorrect.  Think about what surjectivity means: it means for every $y \in G$, you need to SHOW there is some $x \in G$ such that $y  =f(x)$.

Yes, $\operatorname{GCD}(t,n) = 1$ is important and you need it in the proof of injectivity.

Comment: Sorry I typed the proof to show $f$ is an homomorphism